# How to uninstall ffmpeg installed via Firefox addon YouTube Video and Audio Downloader 0.5.2?

Tags: firefox, plugins, ffmpeg

Firefox Addon YouTube Video and Audio Downloader 0.5.2 URL is https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/youtube-video-and-audio-dow/?src=api. After ffmpeg is installed, YouTube Downloaders (YouTube-dlg,ClipGrab,4K Video Downloader) can't handle the .flv video format. How to uninstall ffmpeg installed via Firefox addon YouTube Video and Audio Downloader 0.5.2?

Comment: First delete the extension. Then there should still be an ffmpeg file in your Firefox profile folder. Delete it. Of course back up your profiles folder first, etc. in case of unintended consequences in your configuration.

Comment: Where is ffmpeg profile file? what name of  ffmpeg profile file?

Comment: The file name is "ffmpeg", and it is in your Firefox profile folder. In my system the path to the profile folder is Home --> .mozilla --> Firefox --> (somefilename.default).

Comment: In my system the path to the profile folder is firefox->7wk1n8vh.default->extensions But ffmpeg file is no exist What can I do?

Comment: It is in the main (.default) folder, not the extensions folder. In the extensions folder, there should not be a corresponding folder for the extension you removed.

Comment: I removed ffmpeg file but still can't handle .flv video format I should handle .flv video format And I found more ffmpeg related files How to remove ffmpeg related files?

below are ffmpeg related files

/var/cache/apt/archives/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_50.0.2661.102-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1117_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra.list
/usr/bin/ffmpeg
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/postprocessor/ffmpeg.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/postprocessor/ffmpeg.pyc
/usr/lib/chro

~~~etc

Comment: I don't have those files. You must have something else installed that created them. How did you install ffmpeg? That and your Ubuntu version should be added to your question. You can check in the Ubuntu Software Center if you have an ffmpeg video plugin installed (I have a Gstreamer ffmpeg video plugin). If you do, you could try uninstalling it from there, if you are reasonably certain nothing else is using it. Otherwise, it might be related to your youtube download add-ons, though I have not used them so I can't say about the relationship between them and your problem.

Comment: I installed ffmpeg via Firefox addon YouTube Video and Audio Downloader 0.5.2  After ffmpeg is installed,some ffmpeg files installed with 
My Ubuntu is Ubuntu 14.0.4.2 LTS

Comment: In the Ubuntu Software Center, do you have an ffmpeg video plugin/program installed (search by "ffmpeg")? If so you can remove it. Otherwise you have to ask the add-on author how to uninstall it.